# Unable to get eslint-plugin-graphql to notice deprecated fields

Tags: vue.js, graphql, eslint

I can't get [eslint-plugin-graphql](https://github.com/commercetools/sunrise-spa/blob/a2b1759f0fdd26e076c0a6c2d9ce48e1c8f0d4d5/package.json#L64) to notice a [deprecated](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercetools/sunrise-spa/9d5f9b69b9068ae28f7a926f2fa6653b7c352e0b/graphql.schema.json) field (look for `"deprecationReason": "Use localizedDescription"`) when I use it [in a query file](https://github.com/commercetools/sunrise-spa/blob/ece163ef3be3e41d3c731b21991f0decddb3aa5d/src/components/Cart.gql#L48).

When running [yarn lint](https://github.com/commercetools/sunrise-spa/blob/a2b1759f0fdd26e076c0a6c2d9ce48e1c8f0d4d5/package.json#L9) it does not find anything wrong. Tried to add the [rules](https://github.com/commercetools/sunrise-spa/blob/ece163ef3be3e41d3c731b21991f0decddb3aa5d/.eslintrc.js#L40-L71) to .eslintrc.js:

```
'graphql/template-strings': [
  'error',
  {
    env: 'literal',
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    schemaJson: require('./graphql.schema.json'),
  },
],
'graphql/no-deprecated-fields': [
  'error',
  {
    env: 'relay',
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    schemaJson: require('./graphql.schema.json'),
  },
],
'graphql/no-deprecated-fields': [
  'error',
  {
    env: 'apollo',
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    schemaJson: require('./graphql.schema.json'),
  },
],
'graphql/no-deprecated-fields': [
  'error',
  {
    env: 'literal',
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    schemaJson: require('./graphql.schema.json'),
  },
],
```

But it won't find the deprecated field.

It must be vue related because if I run eslint myself it will give me the error:

```
myComputer$ node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js ./src/components/Cart.gql 

/Path/to/project/src/components/Cart.gql
  48:7  error  The field ShippingMethod.description is deprecated. Use localizedDescription  graphql/no-deprecated-fields

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

I was also [not able](https://github.com/apollographql/eslint-plugin-graphql/issues/299) to run the linter directly and have it detect errors in both js and gql files. But that may be a different question.